# Very Basic Angular Scenario Not Working

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone tell me why this extremely basic example in Angular does not work?

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
        Hi, {{firstName}} {{lastName}}!
    </div>
</div>

function DemoCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.firstName = "Steve";
    $scope.lastName = "Smith";
}
```

It gives the error "Argument 'DemoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined" . . . JsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/SfU3z/

Comment: It's just an issue with how your fiddle is setup. Here's a modified example that works fine with the same code. http://jsfiddle.net/7TJfk/1/

Comment: Oh, wow.  Thank you!  Any insight on what that "no wrap in <head>" JsFiddle option means and why it was needed to make this work?

Comment: @RyanO'Neill Why not posting an answer? :) Than this question could be marked as answered.

Comment: @Flek Ok, I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an issue with how your fiddle is setup. Here's a modified example that works fine with the same code. jsfiddle.net/7TJfk/1